# How can I count occurrences of element in dataframe array?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, jupyter-notebook

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
df = spark.sql("""

SELECT list

FROM categories

""")
```

df.show()

| list |
| --- |
| 1,1,1,2,2,apple |
| apple,orange,1,2 |

And I want result something like this

| list | frequency_count |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 4 |
| 2 | 3 |
| apple | 2 |
| orange | 1 |

This is what I tried.

```
count_df = df.withColumn('count', F.size(F.split('list', ',')))
count_df.show(truncate=False)

df.createOrReplaceTempView('tmp')
freq_sql = """
    select list,count(*) count from
        (select explode(flatten(collect_list(split(list, ',')))) list
        from tmp)
    group by list
"""
freq_df = spark.sql(freq_sql)
freq_df.show(truncate=False)
```

And I'm getting this error

> ```
> AnalysisException: cannot resolve 'split(df.`list`, ',', -1)' due to
> data type mismatch: argument 1 requires string type, however,
> 'df.`list`' is of array<string> type.;
> ```

Comment: Why not just `SELECT col, COUNT(*)
FROM categories c
    LATERAL VIEW EXPLODE(list) l
GROUP BY col
ORDER BY col DESC`.  Not sure you need to split it if it's an array already.

Answer (score 0):

You are currently trying to [flatten](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.flatten.html) a single `list` type value ,however flatten function for an array expects an array of arrays:

> flatten(arrayOfArrays) - Transforms an array of arrays into a single array.

Hence the resultant error you are facing

You would need to `explode` the list before you try to split it and finally exploding it to transform the elements as rows and finally `groupBy` to get the required count

#### Data Preparation

```
sparkDF = sql.createDataFrame(
        [
          (["1,1,1,2,2,apple"],),
          (["apple,orange,1,1"],),
        ],
        ("list",)
    )
```

#### Explode

```
sparkDF.createOrReplaceTempView("dataset")

sql.sql("""
        SELECT
            explode(list) as exploded
            ,list
        FROM dataset
""").printSchema()

root
 |-- exploded: string (nullable = true)
 |-- list: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)


+----------------+------------------+
|        exploded|              list|
+----------------+------------------+
| 1,1,1,2,2,apple| [1,1,1,2,2,apple]|
|apple,orange,1,1|[apple,orange,1,1]|
+----------------+------------------+
```

#### Group By

```
sql.sql("""
        SELECT
            exploded
            ,count(*) as count
        FROM (
            SELECT
                EXPLODE(SPLIT(list,",")) as exploded
            FROM (
                SELECT
                    EXPLODE(list) as list
                FROM dataset
            )
        )
        GROUP BY 1
""").show()

+--------+-----+
|exploded|count|
+--------+-----+
|  orange|    1|
|   apple|    2|
|       1|    5|
|       2|    2|
+--------+-----+
```